# How could i get receive the data from kafka topic to my Streaming Structured DataFrame?

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I know how to consume the data from my Kafka topic, but I can't get the right data in the right column.

I receive the data all my data in the column **value** in this format :

```
{"timestamp":"2021-11-09T11:03:48.955+01:00","time":"1","duration":"0","SourceComputer":"C1707","SourcePort":"N1","DestinationComputer":"C925","start/end":" "}
```

Some of the fields are empty  "  "  and others have some data inside (ex: "C1707").
I was thinking i could use the function:

```
DataFrame=DataFrame.withColumn(ColumnName[i],split(DataFrame["value"],',').getItem(i))
```

but I can't get the exact data in the exact column.

```
+--------------------+--------------------+----+--------+--------------+----------+-------------------+---------+
|               value|           timestamp|time|duration|SourceComputer|SourcePort|DestinationComputer|start/end|
+--------------------+--------------------+----+--------+--------------+----------+-------------------+---------+
|{"timestamp":"202...|{"timestamp":"202...|null|    null|          null|      null|               null|     null|
+--------------------+--------------------+----+--------+--------------+----------+-------------------+---------+
```

Any idea of how I could receive my data in the right way ?

Thank you !

Comment: Please show your complete Spark code. Others, read https://databricks.com/blog/2017/04/26/processing-data-in-apache-kafka-with-structured-streaming-in-apache-spark-2-2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **from_json** method, you can convert JSON string on the Spark DataFrame column to a struct type.
Then you can convert you're struct type to the desired dataframe

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.from_json
val schema = new StructType()
    .add("col1", StringType, true)
    .add("col2", StringType, true)
    .add("col3", StringType, true)
val df4=df.withColumn("value",from_json(col("value"),schema))
val df5=df4.select(col("value.*"))
```

Please refer to [this link](https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/spark-from_json-convert-json-column-to-struct-map-or-multiple-columns/), everything is explained here.